# Biblatex: How to suppress the pages suffix in \cite?

Tags: biblatex

I am using Biblatex for my references. Since the beginning of my thesis, I was always using the command `\cite[page]{Author.2018}` to show the source of the sentence, paragraph, figure or whatever. For the example `\cite[5]{King.1963}`, my template creates the following result:

> I have a dream [KING63, p. 5].

Unfortunately, my professor told me to avoid all pages in the references - this would be too much. I know I could delete all brackets of the cite command to delete the pages as well. But I think there is an automatic solution available. My question: Is there any command to suppress the suffix of a cite command to get:

> I have a dream [KING63].

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is probably

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{postnote}}
```

Comment: In the spirit of https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7711/35864 I would like to emphasise that this is a bad idea if you are not forced by your professor to do this. Page numbers and more precise pinpoint references are really useful in general and should ideally not be suppressed.

Comment: I am totally with you. I was using page information all the time because for other people who read the document (it is a phd thesis), it would be very helpful to find the detail source of it. However, he is the guy who evaluates my thesis. But again: I agree with your statement!